# How to determine the integral interval? Can they be exchanged?

Tags: integration

$\iint_D\frac{\sin y}{y}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$, $D$ with $y=\sqrt{x}$ and $y=x$

What I'm most puzzled about is $\iint_D\frac{\sin y}{y}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$=$\int_0^1\mathrm{d}y\int_{y^2}^y\frac{\sin y}{y}\mathrm{d}x$

*Can $y$ and $y^2$ exchange their position? Can their upper and lower limits be exchanged?*

When I saw the picture, the two equations intersect at one point

Comment: When you saw the graph, did you notice that $x=y$ was right of $x = y^2$ for the given domain?

Answer (score 1):

The equations $y=\sqrt x$ and $y=x$ intersect in two points, $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$.  Over the range $0-1$ in $x$ we have $y^2 \lt y$ so the limits are correct to give a positive result.  You can interchange the limits of an integral, but it will negate the result.  You seem to be assuming that $y^2 \gt y$, but that is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Using your bounds you get

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\sin y}{y}\left[ \int_{y^2}^{y}dx\right]dy=\int_0^1\sin y dy-\int_0^1y \sin y dy=1-\sin (1)$$